# Blackboard WebServices Create Term

Tags: web-services, blackboard

I am trying to create a term via a webservice using c#. I have included the BbWsClient in my solution and believe I am pretty close.

The issue I appear to be having has something to do with the TermVO.sourcedidId. Is there a recommended way to populate this value? Is is supposed to be just a new GUID?

I am trying to use this method to save the term:
http://library.blackboard.com/ref/8c09eac0-db9b-4c1f-839a-69ce42234bdf/blackboard/ws/course/CourseWSImpl.html#saveTerm(blackboard.ws.course.TermVO)

When I don't include it I am getting this error:

> [WSFW000]blackboard.persist.PersistenceRuntimeException: Required
>   field not set. identifier must be set. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

term.sourcedid_id is an nvarchar2(256) and not nullable.

According to the docs:

"The sourcedid_id - set based on feed from external system or autogenerated for Learn created terms"

Comment: I was able to submit generating my own ID in the source system. Thanks